# execute a script on initialization of an docker init container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker image that spawns container with `/usr/sbin/init` as the `pid 1` and `ppid 0`,
I need to execute a script that does some changes once at runtime. and then let the container start as it start right now, i.e. `/usr/sbin/init` as `pid 1` and `ppid 0`.

I tried [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell) but it executes the script and then the container exits.
What can I do?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing/adding a custom entrypoint. If your container does not make use of entrypoint yet, this is straightforward, just have a `/entrypoint.sh` that is something like

```
#!/bin/bash
your commands
exec $@
```

if your image already makes use of entrypoint, you need to either merge with that EP or call it in yours according to it's requirements. You will also need to add

```
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

to your Dockerfile.

Side note: if your initiation can be completely separated from the runtime container, then you might want to use init-container instead.